# use an array in sql query in nodejs

Tags: sql, node.js, express, middleware

I want to use an array in sql query to filter results. I'm using IN (${indications.map(()=>'?').join(', ')}) to go through all elements of the array. When running my code i see no results in the front and using console.log(indications) i see "undefined". My code:

```
static async getProductsOfIndications(indications){
         try {                   
             const [prodByInd]= await db.query(SELECT products.id_product, products.title, products.description, COUNT(comments.id_comment) AS numberOfComments FROM products INNER JOIN product_indications ON products.id_product = product_indications.id_product LEFT JOIN comments ON products.id_product = comments.id_product WHERE product_indications.id_indication IN (${indications.map(()=>'?').join(', ')})  GROUP BY products.id_product, products.title, products.description, products.image_name, products.price ORDER BY numberOfComments DESC LIMIT 0, 25,[indications])
             return [prodByInd]
         }catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            throw new Error('Erreur lors de la récupération des produits qui correspondent à ces indications')
        }
    }
```

```
static async productsByIndic(req, res, next) {
   try {
      
          const {indications}=req.body
       const productsIndications = await productModel.getProductsOfIndications(indications)

       if (productsIndications.code) {
           res.json({ status: 500, msg: 'Une erreur s\'est produite lors de l\'affichage des produits des indications choisies!', err: productsIndications })
       } else {
           res.json({ status: 200, result: productsIndications })
       } 
   } catch (error) {
       console.error(error)
       res.json({ status: 500, msg: 'Une erreur s\'est produite lors de l\'affichage des produits des indications choisies!', err: error })
   }}
```

Comment: Have you tried to look at the resulting querytext and (if you have access to) check what the database is logging for your request?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand your response, i'm new to nodejs

Comment: Try either put `[...indicatons]` or `indications` instead of `[indications]` in db.query(...)

Comment: it doesn't work